# -bash: gshuf: command not found No such file or directory

Tags: bash, macos

Had to re-install osx 10.11 El Capitan after a HDD failure.

Copied my old .profile from Time Machine backup, the last line of which was:

```
fortune | cowsay -f $(ls /usr/local/Cellar/cowsay/3.03/share/cows | gshuf -n1)
```

I have neither fortune or cowsay installed on 10.11, but after removing the last line from .profile, bash displays:

```
-bash: gshuf: command not found
ls: /usr/local/Cellar/cowsay/3.03/share/cows: No such file or directory
```

every time I start a new terminal session/window.

I've searched ~/ but can't find where or what is causing the error to continue to appear.

Comment: Make sure you removed the entire line.

Comment: `grep -rnI gshuf ~/`

Comment: Bingo. Seems there was another alias in .profile that grep -rnI gshuf ~/ turned up.